# ANTLR 4 Java Target: How to implement initial default value of primitive types?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I am implementing my language (interpreter) on Visitor. My language specifies all Java primitive types and their declaration syntax. I have to set their default value like javac does. Just as to remind:

```
Type    Default Value

boolean false
char    '\u0000'
byte    0
short   0
int     0
long    0L
float   0.0f
double  0.0d
```

I have some doubts specially for the integer types if they are ok for both language implementation (as interpreter) and a compiler implementation based on the same visitor. Any additional link or good documentation regarding this also will be a great help!

Comment: what does this have to do with ANTLR?

Comment: My language parser is written on ANTLR 4 and being implemented using ANTLR generated AST walker that is Visitor class.

Comment: Yes, but using ANTLR has nothing to do with the default values. You can implement them however you like in further stages of the compiler or interpreter. They don't belong in the frontend.

Comment: Thanks. I understood. Still I am wondering if the mentioned initial default values like 0 are ok or  the lowest - (minus) value are also ok as default value just like -128 for the type byte etc.

Comment: Why change what already works for Java? The users of your language would be surprised if the defaults are not what they expect. Depending on your language though, you can forbid uninitialized values and make it an error. There are many options